# Unable to Start BlueZ - D-Bus Setup Failed

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth, raspberrypi

Running Ubuntu Server v18 on Raspberry Pi Model 3

Attempting to start Bluez service from systemd fails due to:

> D-Bus setup failed: Connection "1.37" is not allowed to own the service org.bluez due to security policies in the configuration file.

Logs were scanned for AppArmor denials, none were found.

What security policy and configuration file is the message referring to?

Comment: Problem resolved by creating system-local.conf in /etc/dbus-1. Allow root to own org.bluez.

Comment: Hi @blue I'm facing the same issue. It'll be helpful if you could post your solution in a bit more detail.

Answer (score 0):

For me (Bluez: 5.50), all I needed to do was to
edit `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` and add `ControllerMode=le` .

Then reboot.