# DBus Setup Fails, Connection Cannot Own The Service "org.bluez"

Tags: bluetooth, dbus, bluez, blueman

I want to use bluetooth, but it's not working. I've traced the problem to the result of bluetoothd:

> D-Bus setup failed: Connection ":1.88" is not allowed to own the service "org.bluez" due to security policies in the configuration file

Things I have tried:

- [Changing controller mode to Le](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1150867/unable-to-start-bluez-d-bus-setup-failed)
- Reinstalling everything multiple times.
- Reloading DBus, restarting computer, letting computer sit for a while.
- Installing and Building Bluez from the Github Repo
- Making sure rfkill is not blocking connections

Here are the results of various commands people have asked me to try:

inxi -Fxz

> Bluetooth:    Device-1: MediaTek Wireless_Device type: USB driver:
> btusb v: 0.8
> bus-ID: 1-6:5    Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 0 state: down bt-service: enabled,
> running rfk-block: hardware: no software: no   address:

nmcli

> enp13s0: connected to Wired connection 1
>
> lo: connected (externally) to lo
>
> wlp14s0: connected to MyNetwork

Rfkill list

> 0: hci0: Bluetooth    Soft blocked: no    Hard blocked: no 1: phy0:
> Wireless LAN  Soft blocked: no    Hard blocked: no

Blueman dosen't work while this is the case. My busconfig files (bluetooth.conf and system.conf) are both in default state, I would be happy to provide them if helpful. Thank you in advance, please ask for any more information you would need to help me solve this problem.

Comment: In `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` I have everything commented out, including `#ControllerMode = dual` except for the very last line: `AutoEnable=true`

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look at that and report back.

Comment: mine is exactly the same. Still getting the same issue